# Windows 8 is regularly checking in with a connected CIFS share, exactly every 5 minutes. How can I determine what is causing this?

Tags: windows-8, smb, cifs

I have a windows 8 client which makes use of a CIFS share on my LAN. Even when the client is completely idle, something is connecting to the CIFS share every 5 minutes. What sucks is that this prevents the NAS hosting the share from every spinning down the disks.

How can I find out what is doing this? Is there some relevant sysinternals utility which will indicate what is making the calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There was an offline files sync setup for one of the directories within the share. (Discovered after tcpdumping).

Unfortunately there wasn't a direct way to tune offline files to not sync as often, but I did find a registry key which seems to have addressed it:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\NetCache\AgentFillPeriodMin`

Setting this to a DWORD and a decimal value higher than 5 appears to have addressed my issue. This registry key doesn't exist by default, and doesn't seem documented, but I was able to find it on this blog post: https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/04/windows-7-offline-files-survival-guide/.